# Should we merge 'math' and 'maths' into 'mathematics'?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

As a speaker of British English, I will always put the 's' in 'maths' if I am typing. However, you Americans believe the correct spelling is [math](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math). This can be annoying for speakers of British English when they are told they don't have enough rep to create a new tag or have to edit to change the spelling seen as correct in their dialect of the language to the accepted spelling in a different dialect. It also mildly annoys me every time I see it written down, as I instantly think ⟨Oh look, they've spelt it wrong,⟩ which is a bit frustrating as it happens almost every time I look at the site.

I propose, so that everyone is happy and it doesn't matter which way you spell it, that we create a new tag [mathematics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) and make [math](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) and [maths](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maths) synonyms of it.